# Different backup through deja dup

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup, deja-dup

Since Ubuntu one is being dropped, I will have to make my system backup elsewhere.

I asume that in deja dup, in the storage tab, the backup location `Ubuntu one`, will no longer be available. My question is,What can i use in place of the Ubuntu One.

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or preferably [Mega](https://mega.co.nz/), or anything else that allows me to make a backup online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deja Dup is just a front-end (and configuration helper) for Duplicity. From its `--help`, you can see what it supports:

```
  cf+http://container_name
  file:///some_dir
  ftp://user[:password]@other.host[:port]/some_dir
  ftps://user[:password]@other.host[:port]/some_dir
  hsi://user[:password]@other.host[:port]/some_dir
  imap://user[:password]@other.host[:port]/some_dir
  rsync://user[:password]@other.host[:port]::/module/some_dir
  rsync://user[:password]@other.host[:port]/relative_path
  rsync://user[:password]@other.host[:port]//absolute_path
  s3://other.host/bucket_name[/prefix]
  s3+http://bucket_name[/prefix]
  scp://user[:password]@other.host[:port]/some_dir
  ssh://user[:password]@other.host[:port]/some_dir
  swift://container_name
  tahoe://alias/directory
  webdav://user[:password]@other.host/some_dir
  webdavs://user[:password]@other.host/some_dir
  gdocs://user[:password]@other.host/some_dir
  mega://user[:password]@other.host/some_dir
  dpbx:///some_dir
```

And as you can see, both Mega and Dropbox are both on the end of that list. I would expect most of those to be available through Deja Dup.

**Note:** This appears to be new in Trusty. So you would either need to upgrade (pre-release at the time of writing) or manually [suck the `duplicity` package back from packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/duplicity). If you do the second, just check you can fulfill all the dependencies from your Ubuntu version before you upgrade. If you can't and you install anyway, that can cause a bit of a headache.

Comment: Tested on 13.10. Dropbox and Mega are not supported on it. Guess i will have to wait until stable trusty then.

Comment: You could probably suck the [Trusty package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/duplicity) without too many issues. Just check you're not going to cause some sort of dependency Hell. (But I should point out that this is not how Ubuntu is designed to be used and could cause more problems that it's worth. Do at your own risk, etc, yada, blah).

Comment: no go dependencies hell.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using the graphical interface is to install Dropbox on your system, create a folder within the Dropbox folder. After doing those steps point the backup to it using the custom location choice. After the backup is complete the Dropbox client will automatically upload the backup to the cloud.

Comment: Already did that. But not exactly a recommended practice?

Comment: What is basically any different than using Ubuntu One?

Comment: Deja backup, does not support dropbox(on Ubuntu 13.10).

Comment: Sorry, just noticed your reply above to Oli. Are you saying that Deja does not give a URI for Dropbox or that Dropbox does not work with 13.10?

Comment: Deja does not give a URI for dropbox. Dropbox itself works fine on Ubuntu

Comment: OK,that is what I thought. I did it this way on 12.04 as a workaround when I discovered Ubuntu One was going down. It works from what I see here. As a edit to my initial response I chose local file rather than custom *after* creating the file within the Dropbox folder.